# In vim is it possible to use the same regex escaping rules for :substitute and search?

Tags: regex, search, vim, syntax

If I do a search (with magic) like: `/\v\$[^ ]+\$` I get matches in my file, however if I substitute with the same search pattern: `:%smagic/\$[^ ]+\$//`, I need to escape the `+`.

Is it possible to make the escaping behave in the same way for magic search and magic substitute?

Comment: Wow! I didn't even know `:smagic` was a command! Granted I'll find much more use for its cousin `:snomagic` or `:sno`, but I learned about that just now also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:smagic` is like `:s` with `'magic'` on, which is the default (and should not be changes for plugin portability, as its `:help` notes). The `\v` special atom specifies ***very*** *magic*, so additional atoms (like `\+`) do not need the preceding backslash.

There's no corresponding `:s` command variant, but why don't you just keep the `\v` in the pattern:

```
:%s/\v\$[^ ]+\$//
```

(Also, if you've previously searched for that, you can leave off the pattern completely: `:%s///`.)

Answer (score 0):

use `\v` instead of `magic`

```
:%s/\v\$[^ ]+\$//
```